# How to stop strange symbols from being read in the beginning of a getline string C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this function that imports strings from a .txt file, but when I import using getline the very **first** string shows up with 3 strange symbols attached to the front. Every other string comes out fine.

I don't know if it's the file itself, but I tried making a new file and it still reads in the strange symbols.

I tried a similar function with different data from a different .txt file (still strings) and I had no strange symbols at all.

```
void SavagePlants::importInfo(std::fstream& importFile)
{
    plants = new PlantCare[numPlants];
    int i = 0;

    while (getline(importFile >> std::ws, plants[i].species, '#')) {

        getline(importFile, plants[i].sunlight, '#');
        wrapText(plants[i].sunlight);

        getline(importFile, plants[i].water, '#');
        wrapText(plants[i].water);

        getline(importFile, plants[i].temperature, '#');
        wrapText(plants[i].temperature);

        getline(importFile, plants[i].soil, '#');
        wrapText(plants[i].soil);

        getline(importFile, plants[i].fertilizer, '#');
        wrapText(plants[i].fertilizer);

        getline(importFile, plants[i].dormancy, '#');
        wrapText(plants[i].dormancy);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

This is what the output looks like for the first string:

> ∩╗┐Temperate Sundew

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/601282/%CC%81-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text file begins with a UTF-8 BOM (`0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`).  You need to either:

- create your UTF-8 text files without a BOM present.
- just skip past those bytes before reading the rest of the file.
- `imbue()` a UTF-8 locale into your `fstream` that knows how to recognize and ignore those bytes for you.